# Redshift CTAS and IDENTITY column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In Redshift, how to create a table with CTAS Command and also have an extra identity column

Something like this:

```
CREATE table xy 
(raw_id bigint identity(1, 1)) -- ## NEED TO MAKE THIS WORK
distkey (a)
sortkey (b,c)
AS 
(
  select distinct * from (
  select 
    a,b,c,d
  from ng_datawarehouse.table_x x
  where d <> '' and LPAD(c, 8, '0') = '04122019' 
  union 
  select 
    a,b,c,d
  from ng_datawarehouse.table_y y
  where d <> '' and LPAD(c, 8, '0') = '03122019' 
  ) t
);
```

Comment: I don't have RedShift on hand.  Perhaps you can use `NULL` as a placeholder.  Otherwise, you need to create the table in one step and insert in another.

Comment: Is it suppose to be an immutable table? Or do you want to write to it? If immutable, then just add `row_number() over () as raw_id`